# Python xml-rpc tcp persistent connection

Tags: python, tcp, connection, xml-rpc, keep-alive

I'm using Python's xml-rpc server to handle client/server requests, and noticed like many others who have used xml-rpc libraries that the client by default uses a new TCP connection for every request.  Is there a way to get it to keep reusing the same TCP connection so that the TLS handshake doesn't have to be performed for each TCP connection?  I've read similar questions on many forums, but haven't found a solution yet.